# Oracle - How to parse xml using xmltable

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, xml-namespaces, xmltable

the xml looks like this:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap12:Body>
     <BlockUpload xmlns="http://mftsolutions.com/">
       <data><Block xmlns="http://mftsolutions.com/BlockUploader/Block"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://mftsolutions.com/BlockUploader/Block BlockSchema.xsd">
     <Header>
         <Identifier>ID10567</Identifier>
     </Header>
 </Block></data>
     </BlockUpload>
   </soap12:Body>
 </soap12:Envelope>
```

I want to get the value of element Identifier (ID10567).

I've tried some queries like this, but with no result. Probably I'm missing something in xmlNamespaces declarations:

```
select h_id
from test_xml, 
  xmltable(xmlNamespaces ( default 'http://mftsolutions.com/BlockUploader/Block' 
                          ,'http://mftsolutions.com/' as "mft"
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as "xsi"
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as "xsd"
                          ,'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' as "soap12"),
            '//soap12:Envelope/soap12:Body/BlockUpload/data/Block/Header'
                   PASSING XMLTYPE(xml)
                   COLUMNS
                     h_id VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'Identifier')
```

What I have missed?

sample table for this query:

```
create table test_xml (xml clob);

insert into test_xml values ('<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap12:Body>
     <BlockUpload xmlns="http://mftsolutions.com/">
       <data><Block xmlns="http://mftsolutions.com/BlockUploader/Block"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://mftsolutions.com/BlockUploader/Block BlockSchema.xsd">
     <Header>
         <Identifier>ID10567</Identifier>
     </Header>
 </Block></data>
     </BlockUpload>
   </soap12:Body>
 </soap12:Envelope>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<BlockUpload>` node in XML document belongs to namespace `"http://mftsolutions.com/"`. Reference to this namespace missed in Xpath expression.

Also, `<data>` node in document implicitly belongs to same namespace, so proper XPath for query must look like:

```
'//soap12:Envelope/soap12:Body/mft:BlockUpload/mft:data/Block/Header'
```